# Nullpointerexception when deleting Janusgraph vertex

Tags: nullpointerexception, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

#### Problem

I have a `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex` that I call `v`, and a `JanusGraph` instance I call `graph`.

I attempt to delete `v` with:

```
v.remove();
graph.traversal().tx().commit();
```

but I get a null pointer exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.EdgeSerializer.parseRelation(EdgeSerializer.java:128)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.EdgeSerializer.readRelation(EdgeSerializer.java:73)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.RelationConstructor.readRelation(RelationConstructor.java:75)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.RelationConstructor$1$1.next(RelationConstructor.java:60)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.RelationConstructor$1$1.next(RelationConstructor.java:48)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.remove(AbstractVertex.java:101)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.StandardVertex.remove(StandardVertex.java:101)
    at com.brein.common.graph.TinkerPopGraphDatabase.lambda$deleteVertex$4(TinkerPopGraphDatabase.java:500)
    at com.brein.common.graph.TinkerPopGraphDatabase.retry(TinkerPopGraphDatabase.java:616)
    ... 33 more
```

The following line in the `janusgraph-core` library is where null pointer occurs:

`if (multiplicity.isConstrained()) {`

So it would appear that when the library is reading through all the data for the vertex in order to then delete it, it comes across an edge for which there is no multiplicity?

**My question is:** what  might be the reason I'm unable to delete the vertex here, and what are some ideas for how I might explore this issue?

#### Notes

- I am using Janusgraph version `0.2.0`
- I am using cassandra as the backend data store for the graph database
- My graph contains edge labels of `Simple` and `One-to-one` types
- I get a nullpointer exception also if I try and read the graphSON representation of the vertex

Comment: Can you please update to the newest JanusGraph version and check whether the error still occurs? 0.2.0 is a really old version so your issue could already have been fixed long time ago.